# Passing multiple commands over sshpass

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sshpass

Here is my need
I need to login to a server and execute a command as root.

This is what I wrote :

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -t user@ip "hostname & sudo su - root & vmquery -rn 0 -bx | grep -i scratch | wc -l"
```

The problem is VMQUERY command is not executing as root. Any solution will be helpful

Comment: are you sure you wanted to write `&` (executes command in the background) and not `&&` (logical AND) ? Also, you would be better off runing `sudo  vmquery ...` directly without the `sudo su - root` bit

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with sudo vmquery is I dont have the password for root. The server is preconfigures to give root access when using from authorized non root user by typing sudo su - root. I have tried && as well.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "pass" ssh -tt user@ip << EOF
  sudo su - root
  vmquery -rn 0 -bx | grep -i scratch | wc -l 
EOF

Comment: When I use the above script, it works, but it shows a lot of regulatory warinings which i dont want. I only want the result of the vmquery command to be shown as output

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but I've run out of close votes today.  You don't want to run `sudo` in the background; you want to run `vmquery` under `sudo`:  `sudo -u root vmquery`